# FTP in to server from Visual Studio 2012 to Webhostingpad

Tags: encryption, ftp, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio I click File > Open Web Site... > FTP Site

While entering all of the credentials I do notice that at the bottom of the form it says "Passwords are sent across the network in plaintext (unencrypted text), making them vulnerable to interception"

Once I click okay I then get an error window that ultimately states "Sorry, cleartext sessions are not accepted on this server (421)"

Is there any way I can get VS to start an encrypted session? If not, what should I use? I really don't feel like having to save in Visual Studio then copying over the specific files via another FTP client if I don't have to.